# How to package and publish a collection of TypeScript methods?

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-publish

I am working on publishing a library of in-house methods that need to be made available to other projects. At the moment the library is basically a slew of individual method files. As a sample I've cherry picked a couple of simple methods that have no dependencies and am publishing them to a local Verdaccio instance for testing but I'm not sure of the best steps to take going forward. Here is the current file structure after initial build:

[image: File structure after first build]

At this point importing methods as needed is done by calling

```
import clamp from 'utils/dist/clamp';
```

But this is cumbersome. I would prefer to be able to import the methods as needed by calling

```
import { clamp } from 'utils';
```

This is accomplishable by creating an index.ts in the source and filling it with:

```
export { default as clamp } from './clamp';
export { default as slug } from './slug';
```

But this can't be the right way of doing things. It's a bit messy at the source, and also results in all methods being loaded even if they aren't being used.

What's my best step forward here?

Comment: I'm looking at this very problem right now. Did you find a nice approach, or how did you end up handling the issue?

Comment: I am using tsdx to generate a base package and then augmented it with barrelsby to generate the index.